# Back and restore apache ignite volumes in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, amazon-ebs, backup-strategies

I need to create backups and restore for volumes in aws kubernetes cluster. I was reading about CSI driver in kubernetes docs. Though link below has mentioned the steps but I have few questions

https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/snapshot-restore-feature.html
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment

1. Where does it take backups. No s3 location mentioned anywhere
2. Persistent volume claims, storage classes and persistent volumes are referenced in statefulset.yaml. To enable snapshots and restore from snapshot incase needed. So it create volumes when pod is created.

I am unable to understand how can we plugin snapshot.yaml and restore.yaml to create backups and to restore from backup.

Can anyone advise on this please or share link to appropriate documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the infrastructure to perform a backup. Ignite is a distributed system and its data needs to be consistent across all its nodes. Getting a snapshot of a single volume or even all the volumes connected to a pod is not sufficient.

Instead, try to use the built-in tools. Ignite recently got the [ability to perform snapshots](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/snapshots/snapshots) and GridGain (which is built on Ignite) has [had the ability for some time](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/8.8.13/administrators-guide/snapshots/snapshots-and-recovery).

Comment: Thanks Stephen for reply. As you mentioned apache 2.11.x provides snapshot feature but it doesn't provide incremental snapshots as well as point in time recovery which is important for us.

I was wondering if it is possible to use S3 as backend datastore to ignite caches using CacheStoreAdapters. Just like plugging in any external database with read/write through enabled. Would it have any known problems?

Comment: GridGain has incremental and point-in-time recovery. Writing to S3 should work in principle, but it depends on your throughput and latency requrements.

Comment: thanks, will try and check the parameters mentioned!